# Homotopy Equivalence Of Plane Minus $n$ points

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

.Hello math.stack users. As the title says, I would like to ask about the homotopy equivalnce of $\mathbb R^{2}$ minus $n$ points, with the wedge sums of $n$ circles. Now, I know there are some proofs here and there, but I think I have thought of something else, which I haven't seen somewhere, and for which I'm not sure if it's right or wrong.

So, I thought of going with induction. First, I know that this proposition holds for $n=1$, and for $n=2$. The problem is here. Suppose that the claim is true, if we remove up to $n-1$ points from $\mathbb R^{2}$. Now, we remove from $\mathbb R^{2}$, $n$ points, which are $x_{1},...,x_{n}$. Then, for these points there exists a line, $L$, disjoint from $\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}$, and so that each component of $\mathbb R^{2}\setminus L$ has at least one of these points in it(let $x_{1},...,x_{m}$ in the first, and $x_{m+1},...x_{n}$ in the second). By induction step, we know that first component is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sums of $m$ circles, and the second, to the wedge sums of $n-m$ circles.

So here is my question: from this, can I say that $\mathbb R^{2}\setminus\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}$ is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sums of n circles, or is the whole thought wrong to begin with??

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You are correct that one component is homotopy equivalent to $m$ circles while the other to $n-m$ circles. But how would you combine these two homotopies to create a single homotopy for $n$ circles? There's probably no way to do that, because each homotopy moves points away from $L$ line. And so you break continuity at $L$ line, unless there's some fancy unusual way to combine these two homotopies. Unfortunately homotopies often do not behave nice and rarely can be constructed from smaller pieces.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right, but in $\mathbb R^{2}\setminus\{x_{1},...,x_{n}\}$, I have no line $L$ at the end of the day. I just used it for the induction step. So, now that we have wedge sums of $m$ and of $n-m$ circles, can't I, for example, connect the last circle and the first circle of these wedge sums, respectively, with a line segment to get get what I want?? Again, I don't know if what i'm saying makes any sense, but unless I ask, I will never know.

Comment: You could first contract your line $L$ to a point, and get something like the wedge sum of $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus some points and $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the other points.

Comment: @HelloWorld the devil is in the details. You want to connect those two wedges while preserving global homotopy, the question is: **how?** I encourage you to write it down, try to go step by step and see why such a construction fails. That can teach you alot.